# Issue with pushing command in git bash

Tags: git, git-push

I am trying to push my repository to github using git bash but I'm having trouble with the `git push` command. When I type `git push -u origin master` it shows me this:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Did you add a key to your github account?

Comment: Follow this post, might be helpful: http://zeeelog.blogspot.in/2017/08/the-authenticity-of-host-githubcom.html